# How many and who heard Gita from Lord Krishna?

Tags: bhagavad-gita

Since time was stopped when Lord Krishna told arjun gita then how can sanjay would not be stopped and even if he is not stopped due to the blessing of vedvyas then dratrashtra must be stopped.

Comment: who told you that 'time was stopped' ?

Comment: Time was not stopped. Where did you get this information?

Comment: Time was stopped since Gita has about 700 shloks and it would have taken about two weeks only for Gita.Moreover Lord Krishna also revealed his paramavatar to arjun. If time was not stopped then why others didn't saw it.

Comment: Sorry i did not understand your logic. Others did not see it because they were not given divine eyes. How much time it takes to recite 700 slokas?a cuuple of hours or a bit more is eniugh, and you say it stwo weeks!!!

Comment: No sir time did not stop at all and it does not take that much time.

Comment: As this question was marked duplicate. I went on to read answers on the question that has been already asked, there also some answers state that world was in suspended animation.